# why fseek doesn't work?

Tags: c++, io

I wrote a function that list my file that it's binary and write it with fwrite func from my struct:

```
void ReadFile::printList(){
clearerr(bookFilePtr);
fseek(bookFilePtr,0L,SEEK_SET); // set to begin of file
int counter = 1;
cout << "***************************************************" << endl;
struct book tmp ;
while (!feof(bookFilePtr)){
            fread(bookPtrObj,sizeof(struct book),1,bookFilePtr);   
    cout << bookPtrObj->name << "s1"<< endl;
    cout << bookPtrObj->publisher << "s2"<< endl;
    cout << bookPtrObj->author << "s3" <<endl;
    cout << bookPtrObj->stock << endl;
    cout << bookPtrObj->translation << endl;
    cout << bookPtrObj->trasnlator << "s4" <<endl;
    cout << bookPtrObj->delayDays << endl;
    cout << bookPtrObj->delayPay << endl;
    cout << "***************************************************" << endl;
    fseek(bookFilePtr,counter * sizeof(struct book) ,SEEK_SET); // seek to next data
    counter ++;
}
```

It prints for once all of my file , but didn't quit from my loop. and my func continue to print last data in file.How i do to quit my func and find out to end of file? does fseek work?

Comment: Why are you even bothering to seek? You've already moved the file pointer by (up to) `sizeof(struct book)` bytes anyway. You should actually be checking the result of `fread` on each call anyway, but that's a separate matter.

Answer (score 3):

`while(!feof(bookFilePtr))` is a bad way to do a reading loop. `!feof(...)` does not guarantee that fread will succeed. You should loop *while `fread` succeeds* instead.

```
while(fread(bookPtrObj, sizeof(struct book), 1, bookFilePtr) == 1) {
    //  blah blah do the things
}
```

The call to `fseek` is redundant too: `fread` already advances the file cursor itself, so you don't need to seek.

Answer (score 1):

`while (!feof(f))` does not mean what you think it means. It does not mean 'current position is at end of file', it means 'last read attempted to read past end of file': it's a flag that's set by `fread` and others, and cleared by `fseek` and others. `fread` has a return value. That return value indicates whether the read was successful. Use that as your loop condition.

You're ignoring `fseek`'s return value as well, which is bad for the same reasons, but that isn't the cause of your problem, at least not directly.

BTW, I'm assuming this is just code to experiment with `fseek`, but your `fseek`'s in the loop set the position to where the position should already be, so it adds no value.